# Finding determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix through eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In a question I am given 4 vectors labelled $v_1$ to $v_4$ and a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with the following instructions:

> Compute $Av_i$ for $i = 1, \dots , 4$ and determine which of the vectors $v_i$ are eigenvectors for the matrix $A$. Hence find the determinant and the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

How would I get a determinant using eigenvectors?

Comment: Have you computed each one of the $Av_i$?

Comment: yes, and I found eigenvalues and vectors

Comment: Did you find 3 different eigenvectors?

Comment: yes, with eigenvalues 2,3, and -1

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa Reminder for the second time: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got 3 different eigenvectors and the corresponding eigenvalues, the product of the eigenvalues is the determinant of $A$ since $\chi_A(X) = -\prod_{i=1}^3 (X- \lambda_i)=\det(A-XI_3)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (depending on your definition, you might have learnt $\chi_A(X) = \det(XI_3-A)$).